# Calculating execution time of an algorithm

Tags: java, image-processing, time

I have developed an image processing algorithm in core java (without using any third party API), Now I have to calculate execution time of that algorithm, for this i have used **System.currentTimeMillis()** like that,

```
public class MyAlgo {

   public MyAlgo(String imagePath){
     long stTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     // ..........................
     // My Algorithm
     // ..........................
     long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println("Time ==> " + (endTime - stTime));
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
     new MyAlgo("d:\\myImage.bmp");
   }
}
```

But the problem is that each time I am running this program I am getting different execution time. Can anyone please suggest me that how can I do this?

Comment: computers have many tasks running: so times will always vary...

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.  The blank lines in the source were also mostly redundant.

Comment: @MitchWheat, I have made the system in ideal state, means that no other extra task is executing in my system, except my program and operating system important processes...

Comment: --> "operating system important processes"

Comment: How different are the times you are getting? Generally you should discard the first run, then do at least 10 runs and take the average.

Comment: Micro benchmarks are always a bit hit and miss. There is nothing wrong with doing it that way but you should run it a number of times and do a mean and sd for it. You could use a profile tool like jVisualvm as well, to give an idea of the time spent inside your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use external profiling libraries just wrap your algorithm in a for() loop that executes it 1000 times and divide the total time by 1000. The result will be much more accurate since all the other tasks/processes will even out.

Note: The overall measure time will reflect the expected time of the algorithm to finish and not the total time that algorithms code instruction require.
For example if your algorithm uses a lot of memory and on average java VM calls garbage collector twice per each execution of algorithm - than you should take into account also the time of the garbage collector.
That is exactly what a for() loop does, so you will get good results.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get a reliable result from one execution alone; Java (well, JVMs) does runtime optimizations, plus there are other processes competing for CPU time/resource access. Also, are you sure your algorithm runs in constant time whatever the inputs?

Your best bet to have a calculation as reliable as possible is to use a library dedicated to performance measurements; one of them is [caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/).

Set up a benchmark with different inputs/outputs etc and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply some statistical analysis over multiple executions of your algorithm. For instance, execute it 1000 times and analyze min, max and average time.

Multiple executions in different scenarios might provide insights too, for instance, in different hardware or with images with different resolution.

I suppose your algorithm can be divided in multiple steps. You can monitor the steps independently to understand the impact of each one.

[Marvin Image Processing Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/features.html), for instance, provides methods to monitor and analyze the time and the number of executions of each algorithm step.